# SwiftUI Charts .chartSymbolScale() - Circle to Rectangle change produces the compiler timeout

Tags: swiftui, charts

I have a chart symbol legend at the bottom of a chart. This code works:

```
.chartSymbolScale([
     literals[0].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
     literals[1].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
     literals[2].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
     literals[3].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
     literals[4].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0)
 ])
```

This produces: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

```
.chartSymbolScale([
      literals[0].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
      literals[1].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
      literals[2].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
      literals[3].0: Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0),
      literals[4].0: Rectangle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2.0)
 ])
```

Any ideas? I thought that Circle(), Rectangle() and Capsule() were all allowed. The inline code verifier auto-inserts Rectangle() happily.

Comment: Try removing the array from the modifier and specify the types when you declare the array. Something like that usually helps resolve these problems.

Comment: I am sure that's correct. .chartForegroundStyleScale and .chartSymbolScale to override the normal/in-built scales are rarely used and little support on them, yet. The Apple Dev site seems to have the types as: <DataValue, ChartSymbolShape> but these don't bite. I am clearly mis-reading it.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately little support for charts in general yet. I have had crashes trying to set custom range. With regards to .chartSymbolScale I only used the existing BasicChartSymbolShape's. These conform to the ChartSymbolShape protocol. Maybe try creating a view which conforms to this protocol?

Comment: Will do - very many thanks.